# Block Excel new instance to merge with other Excel instance

Tags: c#, .net-framework, microsoft-excel, windows, process

By default, when we open 2 Excel files, the second one will merge the process with the first one:
`excel.exe file1, excel.exe file2`

[image]

We can use `/x` to open the second Excel file without merge:
`excel.exe file1, excel.exe /x file2`

[image]

I would like to open "file1" and then never merge this process with another file, without using `/x`. Is it possible? Pass a parameters when file1 is open to inform that it must never merge another process? Like:
`excel.exe ??? file1, excel.exe file2`

I'm using C#.

Comment: How are you opening Excel? Can you go into the Registry and adjust the open with arguments there to add this flag?

Comment: The problem is that it's not my computer. I'm developing an application. And I wouldn't want users to be forced to change the registry. So I would like the first excel instance (launched by me) not to merge with the second excel instance (possibly launched by the user)

Comment: It sounds like you have the tools already to solve your problem. You are developing the application and so you can control the parameters by which Excel is opened, and you know the parameter Excel already supports that does what you want. Perhaps I do not understand why you don't want to use this /x argument except as a matter of preference.

Comment: I'll describe the situation I want to avoid to make it clearer:

1) The user opens a personal excel file, any file1.xls, starting the process process1.

2) The user uses my application to open a file2.xls file. As I use "/x", this file is in a process process2.

3)The user then opens another personal file file3.xls. This file goes to the process process2.

The problem is that I can't control how the user will open other excel files while using my application. I use "/x" for file2, but I can't do that for file3.

Comment: That information really needs to be in the question body. We strongly encourage editing on this site to continuously improve the question itself.